# How to add a removed word back into the original text file

Tags: python, variables, text-files, cpu-word

I'm quite new to python. With help from the stack over flow community, I have managed to do part of my task. My program removes a random word from a small text file and assigns it to a variable and puts it in another text file.

However, at the end of my program, I need to put that random word back into the text file for my program to work so someone can use multiple times.

All the words in the text file are in no specific order but each word is on and need to be on a separate line.

This is the program which removes the random word from the text file.

```
with open("words.txt") as f:    #Open the text file
        wordlist = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
        replaced_word = random.choice(wordlist)
        newwordlist = [word for word in wordlist if word != replaced_word]
        with open("words.txt", 'w') as f:    # Open file for writing
            f.write('\n'.join(newwordlist))
```

If I have missed out any vital information which is needed I'm happy to provide that :)

Comment: If you need to put the word back, why take it out in the first place? Just keep `newwordlist` for use in your script, and don't re-write the file (i.e. omit the last two lines of your example code).

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your words.txt file, therefore losing all the words. If you just create  a new file for the random word you don't need to rewrite your original file. Something like :

```
...
with open("words_random.txt", 'w') as f:
    w.write(replaced_word)
```

You will have a new text file with only the random word.

Comment: Will that text file contain all the words when the program is run multiple times without me having to manually enter those words?

Comment: which text file, the original or the one with the random word?

Comment: both of the text files

Comment: the original will remained the same since you will be only reading it. If you want to append words to the other file you can just change the mode in the  open constructor to a. `with open("words_random.txt", 'a') as f:` have in mind that in other to append you first need to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy the text file at the start of your program? Perform what you have so far on your copy so you will always leave the original file unaltered.

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile("words.txt", "newwords.txt")

with open("newwords.txt") as f:    #Open the text file
    wordlist = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    replaced_word = random.choice(wordlist)
    newwordlist = [word for word in wordlist if word != replaced_word]
    with open("newwords.txt", 'w') as f:    # Open file for writing
        f.write('\n'.join(newwordlist))
```

Comment: So when the program is run again, will it be programmed to write over the file "newwords.txt"  so that it is the same as "words.txt" each and every time?